# Constraint font sizes of multiple UILabels to be equal

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have multiple UILabels horizontally aligned next to each other. Since they have different lengths of text, when using auto layout (bind left anchor to the right anchor of the previous label etc.) it isn't sure which label to make larger and which one to make smaller so the widths are different and the font sizes are different as well.
To be clear: it's not important if the width of the labels is different, it's just that they should all have the same font size while still displaying everything in 2 lines.

Comment: Have you set the label's auto shrink to "Fixed font size"?

Comment: No, should I? If so, how do the labels know the font size of the others / constrain them to be equal?

Comment: If you use a fixed font size then the font size can't change from what you have specified in your storyboard.  Set all of the labels to have the same font size.  If you can't fit all of the text in the two lines and you are unwilling to change some font sizes then you will end up with truncation.  The only other approach you can use is to have your app calculate the font size that is required for the longest text and set all of the labels to use that font size.

Comment: I don’t want to explicitly set the font sizes because I want them to be as large as possible while still fitting everything in 2 lines per label and into the width of the device. Also I don’t use Storyboards but that’s besides the point... :D

Comment: You either need to use a fixed font size and risk truncation or you need to dynamically calculate the font size for your largest text and then assign that calculated font to each label - e.g. https://medium.com/@joncardasis/dynamic-text-resizing-in-swift-3da55887beb3 There is no way to tell iOS to automatically use the same dynamic font size

Comment: Okay that’s a pity. Would have loved something like label.fontSize.constraint(equalTo: label2.fontSize).isActive=true

Comment: You might try to combine all these labels into single one